# Backpropagation Algorithm unable to find inverses to matricies

Tags: javascript, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm trying to use a learning AI to get the inverse of a matrix, but if the input matrix has numbers that are too large the AI weights explode to infinity

this is my first time posting so sorry if I don't know proper etiquette,
I'm trying to code a neural network that learns the inverse of a matrix, I know there are better ways of doing that but I'm trying to learn how backpropagation is implemented, comments marked with === I've added to explain what I've tried so far, the main learning functions are below but I can send over more of the file if needed.

```
function performAIStep() 
{
    readTable(); //===sets OG to the input matrix (the one i'm trying to invert)===
    /*
    Step 1:
        Generate 10-100 random inVectors
        Apply matrix multiplication for each inVector to get inoutVectors
        for each inoutVector, apply matrix multiplication to get outVectors
    Step 2:
        for each inVector, calculate the error between it and the outVectors
        perform calculus to get the gradiant of the error squared:
            C=Σ(O-E)^2
            ∇C=2Σ(O-E)*∇O=2Σ((f(Σwi)-E)*f'(Σwi)*∇(Σwi))
            dC/dw=2Σ((f(Σwi)-E)*f'(Σwi)*i)

            the derivative with respect to a weight is the sum of the following for each output
                2 * error * (1 if the neuron is activated, or 0) * the corresponding input strength
    */
    //the gradient will be a 2d matrix
    var costGradient = [];
    var cost = 0;
    for (var i=0;i<OG.length;i++) 
    {
        let newArr = [];
        for (var j=0;j<OG[i].length;j++) newArr.push(0);
        costGradient.push(newArr);
    }

    //for some number of examples
    var randomCount = 1000;
    for (var countIndex=0;countIndex<randomCount;countIndex++) 
    {
        //generate random vectors === these are the inputs to the OG matrix and the expected output
        var randomVector = [];
        //OG[0].length = number of columns
        for (var i=0;i<OG[0].length;i++) randomVector.push(Math.random()-0.5);

        //get the inout vector and outvector
        var inoutVector = matrixMultiplication(OG, randomVector); //===these are the inputs to the inverse matrix
        var outVector = matrixMultiplication(inverseMatrix, inoutVector); //===these are the outputs of the inverse matrix
        var outDer = []; //===store the activation derivate for all outVector
        for (var i=0;i<outVector.length;i++) 
        {
            outDer.push(activationFunctionDerivative(outVector[i])); //store the derivate for later
            outVector[i] = activationFunction(outVector[i]);//since we only train on outVector, we only apply the activation function here

            cost+=(outVector[i]-randomVector[i])**2
        }
        for (var r=0;r<costGradient.length;r++) for (var c=0;c<costGradient[r].length;c++) 
        {
            costGradient[r][c]+=2*(outVector[r]-randomVector[r])*outDer[r]*inoutVector[c];
        }
    }

    //calculate a good learning rate
    var max = costGradient[0][0];
    for (var r=0;r<costGradient.length;r++) for (var c=0;c<costGradient[r].length;c++) max = Math.max(max, costGradient[r][c]);
    var rate = 0.05/max; //===I tried capping the learning rate to fix the problem which works on medium sized inputs

    //divide costGradient by randomCount && iterate inverseMatrix by costGradient
    for (var r=0;r<costGradient.length;r++) for (var c=0;c<costGradient[r].length;c++) 
    {
        costGradient[r][c]/=randomCount;
        inverseMatrix[r][c]-=rate*costGradient[r][c]; //===this is where I think the problem is, but I can't find a good resource online to confirm
    }
    //update visuals
    updateInverseVisual();
}

function activationFunction(input) 
{
    //since this is a matrix our activation function will be o=i:
    return input;
}

//this should return the derivative of activationFunction at the input
function activationFunctionDerivative(input) 
{
    return 1;
}

function matrixMultiplication(matrix, vector) 
{
    var out = []; //out has a length of matrix.length
    for (var i=0;i<matrix.length;i++) out.push(0);
    for (var column = 0;column<vector.length;column++) for (var row = 0; row<matrix.length; row++) 
    {
        out[row]+=vector[column]*matrix[row][column];
    }
    return out;
}
```